# Resolver Permisos de Administrador

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Estoy intentando crear un Archivo TXT pero al ejecutar el Código[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] me lanza el siguiente error

por favor si alguien es tan amable de decirme como puedo resolverlo

Answer (score 1):

Está claro que si intentas acceder así a un fichero dentro de directorio de IIS necesitas los permisos adecuados, o bien sacar el fichero a una ruta donde si tengas permisos. No te recomendaría cambiar los permisos de la carpeta, ya que no creo que en producción te dejen hacer algo así, además del agujero de seguridad que puedes provocar, en todo caso deberías impersonar la aplicación para que cuando intente llegar a esa ruta lo haga con un usuario permitido. Debes hablar con el administrador del website para que te de un usuario con los privilegios adecuados.

Para impersonar el acceso en todas las solicitudes puedes realizarlo por web.config, pero sinceramente no te lo recomiendo, ya que si tiene unos privilegios muy altos puedes crear una brecha de seguridad:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="accountname" password="password" />
```

Te recomiendo hacer la impersonalización cuando vayas a escribir en el fichero, puedes comprobar sus permisos y así evitar errores. OJO el código que te dejo aquí me funciona para sistemas Windows con IIS.

Para impersonar yo he usado esta clase:

```
/// <summary>
/// Clase que permite suplantar el usuario identificado que ejecuta la aplicación en la máquina servidora
/// </summary>
public class SuplantarUsuarioIISBL : IDisposable
{
    #region Librerías Externas
    public const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
    public const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

    WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern int LogonUserA(String lpszUserName,
        String lpszDomain,
        String lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType,
        int dwLogonProvider,
        ref IntPtr phToken);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken,
        int impersonationLevel,
        ref IntPtr hNewToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool RevertToSelf();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
    #endregion

    #region Métodos Públicos
    /// <summary>
    /// Inicia la suplantación de usuario por el indicado en los parámetros
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userName">Usuario</param>
    /// <param name="domain">Dominio de autenticación</param>
    /// <param name="password">Contraseña</param>
    /// <returns>True si consigue validar al usuario e impersonalizarlo</returns>
    public bool ImpersonateValidUser(String userName, String domain, String password)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain))
        {
            WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity;
            IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

            if (RevertToSelf())
            {
                if (LogonUserA(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
                {
                    if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                    {
                        tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                        impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                        if (impersonationContext != null)
                        {
                            CloseHandle(token);
                            CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(token);
            if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Devuelve la suplantación del usuario al original
    /// </summary>
    public void UndoImpersonation()
    {
        if (impersonationContext != null)
        {
            impersonationContext.Undo();
            impersonationContext.Dispose();
            impersonationContext = null;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Implementación de la interfaz
    /// <summary>
    /// Revierte la suplantación de identidad si es que se ha producido y libera todos los recursos utilizados
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        UndoImpersonation();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Y luego se puede usar de la siguiente manera:

```
// Datos del usuario a autenticar
string u = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UsuariosAppLocalAutorizados.LecturaEscrituraDiscoUsuario"];
string d = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UsuariosAppLocalAutorizados.LecturaEscrituraDiscoDominio"];
string p = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UsuariosAppLocalAutorizados.LecturaEscrituraDiscoPassword"];

using (SuplantarUsuarioIISBL suplantarUsuarioBL = new SuplantarUsuarioIISBL())
{
    if (suplantarUsuarioBL.ImpersonateValidUser(u, d, p))
    {
        // Realiza las operaciones que tenga que hacer con ese usuario
    }
}
```

Seguro que a partir de este código puedes encontrar otros que incluso sean más correctos en la implementación.

Espero que te sirva.

Un saludo.